# Bootstrap auto select tab on page load

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I'm using Bootstrap V3 and am wondering if there is a way I can auto select a specific tab when the page loads.  It sounds simple enough but nothing that I try which I expect would work....works.

If I navigate to this in a browser it works fine...(assuming my tab has an ID of `tab_files`)

```
WEBSITE_URL/contact.php?page=contact&token=XYZ#bs-tab-tab_files
```

But, if I were to call the above link from an `a` tag or javascript then it doesn't work.

Am I missing something?

Comment: please post your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you can. Check if there is a hash on the URL using `window.location.hash` and then call `tab('show')` on a link with that href attribute

```
if (window.location.hash) {
    $("a[href='" + window.location.hash + "']").tab('show');
}
```

You can take it a step further and make sure the item is actually a tab, but the above will suffice. Make sure that runs after your DOM is loaded.